# how to dynamically update series data using ember-highcharts

Tags: ember.js, highcharts

I am exploring ember highcharts and i see there is an observer there: "contentDidChange" which they say can be used to change series data and show dynamic updates on the chart. I used the same, and i was able to update the series data but when I invoke chart.redraw() function then my chart does not re-draw itself. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you prepare an online example of your app (jsfiddle, codepen)? Or send your code example?

Comment: Hey thanks, i was able to solve the issue yesterday night.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, I had to create a wrapper to override the properties of the chart and then invoke redraw method. What I learned was, the redraw method itself was not an issue, rather my chart was complex and updating certain properties were messing up the chart because of which redraw did not work. But I think, in such cases redraw method shall throw an exception or something so that it is clear what is the issue.